# Schedule Content Expiration in Orchard CMS | Trigger Workflow etc

Tags: orchardcms, orchardcms-1.7, orchard-modules

How to mark a Custom Content type as Expired/Archived after a specific Date/Time in ORchard CMS ?

Requirement::
I created a custom content type: SideBarLinks. This type contains, among other things, two fields which are :

- ExpirationDate
  Descriptive Text:- Date After which item will be marked Expired:
- ExpirationStatus
  Descriptive Text:- Is The Item Expired?

Please see below image:
[image]

I am really not sure how to proceed further now. How Can I trigger some Function/Workflow/Program which will check the `ExpirationDate` and Set the `ExpirationStatus` accordingly ( Yes/No) ?

I see there is a similar feature called `PublishLater` thing in Orchard CMS, where we can set the Scheduled Publish Date and Time: 
[image]

How is this thing done? is there some `Workflow` being executed automatically at the desired Date of `ScheduledPublish` ? Will be grateful if more details can be provided on implementation here. I have checked the `Orchard.PublishLater` inbuilt module but couldn't make much sense.

Comment: Use the ArchiveLater module, which is part of orchard's core modules

Comment: @devqon: I am afraid that ArchiveLater module is NOT the solution for my requirement. Basically there is an  ARCHIVED page on my Website which will actually list the archived/expired items on LIVE !!! What I really want is after the desired date(ExpirationDate), the  ExpirationStatus should be should be set "YES" and nothing more required.  Is this possible with Archive Module ?

Comment: Not sure what you mean, but with the ArchiveLater module, you can just set 'archive this when this date', and when that date arrives, orchard unpublishes the content item. This should cause the item to be invisible in the frontend, or you somewhere forgot to query for the published contentitems instead of all.

Comment: @devqon: actually there are 2 , say, category of my content type: Either YES or NO for ExpirationStatus field. I  just wrote 2 queries ( to be used by Projection ) to get items with ExpirationStatus field = YES and NO. I don't want to manually set YES ( ExpirationStatus field ) for all contnet item when the date arrives

Comment: The real question here is why do you need to create your own expiration status field whereas there is a perfectly good flag that is built-in and that seems to do exactly what you are trying to do.

Comment: @Bertrand Le Roy: Because I don't want to Unpublish the item after expiration date. There is an ARCHIVED page on website which shows Expired/archived item. I have written a query to retrieve the items for which ExpirationStatus field value is YES. So my requirement was that after the Scheduled date,  option "YES" is selected/updated in the item automatically, which the ArchiveLater module doesn't do

Comment: Then reproduce what the archive later module is doing, but targeting your custom flag instead of the publication bit.

Comment: @Bertrand Le Roy: Ok. Will implement along the lines you said

Answer (score 0):

There's a module that does exactly that in Orchard Gallery https://gallery.orchardproject.net/List/Modules/Orchard.Module.Orchard.ArchiveLater

If you'd like it to use your own fields, you'll have to modify it.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I am afraid that ArchiveLater module is NOT the solution for my requirement. Basically there is an ARCHIVED page on my Website which will actually list the archived/expired items on LIVE !!! What I really want is after the desired date(ExpirationDate), the ExpirationStatus should be should be set "YES" and nothing more required. Is this possible with Archive Module ?